# Prevent Data Driven Pages Strip Index tool from rotating polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

When using [Strip Map Index Features Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/cartography-toolbox/strip-map-index-features.htm) the pages rotate with the linear feature, is there a way to prevent this?

So at the moment I get

[image]

or

[image]

and I want..

[image]

No rotation of polygons.

Using 10.6
Is this possible? I have tried changing between Vertical and Horizontal and the orientations.

Comment: Maybe split line into same length bits and use minimum bounding geometry, envelope, to create rectangles. Might work for geometry shown. To create overaps, perhaps buffer bits or rectangles.

Comment: Can you explain why you want the polygons to be unrotated?

Comment: I want landscape A3 map all north facing. The line is very much predominantly N-S. There is no need for rotation. It was requested to have no rotation.