# Strip Map Index Feature cuts off map parts?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages, strip-map

I am using ArcMap 10.2 on Win 7 SP1.
When I use the SMIF-Tool for creating a mapbook at a fixed scale it seems to have an issue with overlapping the bounding areas correctly in order to get a proper connection to the following map.
In the example I have a DIN A4-Layout (297 x 210 mm, Portrait) and I have these settings:
[image: SMIF-Dialogue]
Given the track I get these results:
[image: Rectangles with rotation]
Within the North-South direction the overlapping works quite fine, but when it comes to West-East, connection parts of the following map are missing because ArcMap starts to rotate the data frame within the process of Data Driven Pages. And once you start taking the value of "length along the line" for "length perpendicular to the line" it must get screwy because you still want to populate a regular DIN A4-Layout having 180 mm usable width with now 260 mm "length along the line". So, therefore there has to be a missing part of approx. 4 cm on each side of the A4-page.
[image: Missing parts] 
My usual workaround at this point is: instead of creating a SMIF use the Grid Index Feature Tool (GIF) based on any given line feature. Within this tool the rectangles have no rotation and they keep in a constant portrait position that is useful for exporting maps within the A4-Layout. The only thing is that I have to bring them in order manually by drag&drop, so I lose quite a bit of automation functionality (sometimes 1000+ rectangles).
[image: GIF draged manually]
No missing parts here.
[image: No missing parts within GIF]
My question: is there any way either to get that SMIF-Tool working properly or to get the GIF-Tool working without manually draging or anything else?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2 is *really* old software, initially released in 2013, with the 10.2.2 terminal service pack release in 2014. It was placed in Retired status earlier this month. If you haven't reviewed the bugfix lists for 10.2.1 and 10.2.2, you probably should.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2 may be a few years old, but I have expirienced the above behaviour on ArcGIS 10.0 and 10.3 as well. I have also read about a user right here in this platform using 10.6 and being unable to prevent DDP from rotating the rectangles. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318397/prevent-data-driven-pages-strip-index-tool-from-rotating-polygons